# Pros & cons of using struct to enforce validation of built-in type

Tags: c#, .net

**Update:** [Reposted on Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268201/pros-cons-of-using-struct-to-enforce-validation-of-built-in-type) due to being put on hold as primarily opinion-based.

Commonly domain objects have properties which can be represented by a built-in type but whose valid values are a subset of the values which may be represented by that type.

In these cases, the value can be stored using the built-in type but it is necessary to ensure values are always validated at the point of entry, otherwise we might end up working with an invalid value.

One way to solve this is to store the value as a custom `struct` which has a single `private readonly` backing field of the built-in type and whose constructor validates the provided value. We can then always be sure of only using validated values by using this `struct` type.

We can also provide cast operators from and to the underlying built-in type so that values can seamlessly enter and exit as the underlying type.

Take as an example a situation where we need to represent the name of a domain object, and valid values are any string which is between 1 and 255 characters in length inclusive. We could represent this using the following struct:

```
public struct ValidatedName : IEquatable<ValidatedName>
{
    private readonly string _value;

    private ValidatedName(string name)
    {
        _value = name;
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string name)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && name.Length <= 255;
    }

    public bool Equals(ValidatedName other)
    {
        return _value == other._value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is ValidatedName)
        {
            return Equals((ValidatedName)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(ValidatedName x)
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }

    public static explicit operator ValidatedName(string x)
    {
        if (IsValid(x))
        {
            return new ValidatedName(x);
        }
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ValidatedName x, ValidatedName y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ValidatedName x, ValidatedName y)
    {
        return !x.Equals(y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

The example shows the to-`string` cast as `implicit` as this can never fail but the from-`string` cast as `explicit` as this will throw for invalid values, but of course these could both be either `implicit` or `explicit`.

Note also that one can only initialize this struct by way of a cast from `string`, but one can test whether such a cast will fail in advance using the `IsValid` `static` method.

This would seem to be a good pattern to enforce validation of domain values which can be represented by simple types, but I don't see it used often or suggested and I'm interested as to why.

So my question is: what do you see as being the advantages and disadvantages of using this pattern, and why?

If you feel that this is a bad pattern, I would like to understand why and also what you feel is the best alternative.

Comment: To me validator's are domain logic accessible through either a factory or static class in a very specific namespace. i.e : `MyApp.Validators` and class specific validator within that namespace such as `ClientValidator` which contain all validation. I really don't see the use of a struct here

Comment: Come on guys, Candidate for migrating to programmers exchange perhaps, definitely not merely opinion though

Comment: I would provide my answer, but with 1 close vote remaning to get the Q&A closed......

Comment: Obvious drawback as you can see is writing a bulk of code.

Comment: If it gets closed, I'll be voting to reopen. Compared to some of the questions we get this is well above par.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I did debate with myself whether this was the right place to ask this question given it is subjective but felt it was worth asking here. As you can see I've not so far been a significant contributor in either direction but am certainly quite a prolific consumer and haven't really seen this question addressed, specifically in relation to built-in types.

Comment: This is going to be closed mistakenly. Reask on programmers and leave a link here. With 4 close votes pending this question is dead. It deserves better.

Comment: @L-Three you're not doing this question a service. Even if reopened it is no longer getting the attention it should be getting. This is a great question for a more lenient site such as Programmers.

Comment: This has been reposted on Programmers: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/268201/pros-cons-of-using-struct-to-enforce-validation-of-built-in-type (leaving a comment because edits are easily overlooked).

Answer (score 0):

Your way is a fair bit of code, you've had to add equality testing and casting when your intent was to validate.

Where are you at if you need validatedname2 which can't be null or whitespace and be between 8 & 16 characters in length with no punctuation and then ValdatedNameType3...

Mine would be using attributes, e.g. allowed_blank and maximum length or perhaps even a regex

Comment: That's a good idea. He could be adding attributes to every property and then create a method that take any class and uses reflection to grab all validator attributes and apply them to the properties one by one. Very generic and extensible.

Comment: I agree that in cases where there are many such types this could become a handful to create them all, but for many types this could be achieved using templates as there are only so many types of validation which can be necessary for values that can be represented using built-in types.

Comment: Issues that I see with using attributes: firstly if the domain value type is used in multiple places, it is necessary to add those attributes to every usage, which could be messy and easily get out of sync. Secondly and perhaps more importantly, this requires you to be in a situation where you are using attribute-based validation. I suppose this perhaps boils down to the more fundamental question of where validation of domain objects should be handled. But I realize that is a much more fundamental, wider and subjective question.

Comment: Used in multiple places is a potential downside, but the upside is you do one attribute per validation behaviour. Clean and simple. You don't have to introduce many different types, before you get into a significant mess either. If you know there aren't going to be many different types, then it's a decent compromise. I've been in few situations where despite being assured there wouldnlt me many, there was always one more...

Answer (score 0):

Your way is quite heavy and intensive. I typically define domain entities like:

```
public class Institution
{
    private Institution() { }

    public Institution(int organizationId, string name)
    {
        OrganizationId = organizationId;            
        Name = name;
        ReplicationKey = Guid.NewGuid();

        new InstitutionValidator().ValidateAndThrow(this);
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; private set; }

    ... other properties    

    public Department AddDepartment(string name)
    {
        var department = new Department(Id, name);
        if (Departments == null) Departments = new List<Department>();
        Departments.Add(department);            
        return department;
    }

    ... other domain operations
}
```

In the entity's constructor, validation is triggered using FluentValidation.NET, to make sure you cannot create an entity with invalid state. Note that properties are all readonly - you can only set them through the constructor or dedicated domain operations.

Validation of this entity is a separate class:

```
public class InstitutionValidator : AbstractValidator<Institution>
{
    public InstitutionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(institution => institution.Name).NotNull().Length(1, 100).WithLocalizedName(() => Prim.Mgp.Infrastructure.Resources.GlobalResources.InstitutionName);       
        RuleFor(institution => institution.OrganizationId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(institution => institution.ReplicationKey).NotNull().NotEqual(Guid.Empty);
    }  
}
```

These validators can also be easily reused, and you write less boilerplate code.

Comment: This is the type of pattern that seems to be much more common. But does this not suffer from the drawback that validation of, for example, the Institution's Name, is tied to the use of the name as a property of an Institution? What if we want to use a disembodied Institution Name away from the context of an Institution object?

Comment: In that case you could create a more general InstitutionNameValidator, used in various entities. As these validators are reusable, you can do whetever you want...

Comment: Yes that would be a more directly equivalent pattern, though you still have to make sure you keep track of when values have been validated and when they haven't, and you might potentially end up validating the same thing repeatedly, or far worse not at all. There is also the overhead of creating a Validator object whenever you wish to validate, or at least having one to hand, which may or may not be an issue depending on the scenario.

Comment: I don't see any overhead compared to your solution :) I find it more flexible and much less work. But that's my opinion.

Comment: And I greatly appreciate it. I realize the question is subjective but I asked it to understand what the specific reasons are why it does not seem to be a common pattern (or alternatively why it may be an under-used pattern). You've provided justification for preferring the alternative pattern you described and that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Just think of another advantage of this fluent validation thing: readability :)